# Emitting a js event to Livewire with data

Tags: laravel, eventemitter, laravel-echo, laravel-livewire

I have a component where each row is a separate component. I'm emitting an event using Echo + Pusher, and I want to scope the event to only refresh the relevant row.

This isn't described in the docs, but there's an old (and possibly outdated) video by Caleb Porzio (creator of Livewire) in [this article](https://calebporzio.com/video-realtime-livewire-w-laravel-echo-pusher) (last video, ~8m30s) where this is done by adding the relevant ID into the event name.

In my livewire model, I have:

```
public function getListeners()
{
    return [
        "HitReceived:{$this->monitorId}" => 'refresh',
    ];
}
```

And in my JS I have:

```
Livewire.emit('HitReceived:' + data.monitorId);
```

I can see in the console that `data.monitorId` is set. When I fire an event with id #1, I get a 500 error:

```
ERROR: Undefined array key "HitReceived1" {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):
Undefined array key \"HitReceived1\" at /vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentConcerns/ReceivesEvents.php:72)
```

(This all works if I don't scope my event to a particular model instance, but then everything refreshes.)

Comment: Could it be that `$this->monitorId` is not defined as you expect it to be inside the `getListeners()` method?

Comment: Also, if you want to use Laravel Echo, there's a specific prefix for that. See https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/laravel-echo

Answer (score 0):

I was using `$this->monitorId` in my array of listeners:

```php
public function getListeners()
{
    return [
        "HitReceived:{$this->monitorId}" => 'refresh',
    ];
}
```

But the variable was declared as `protected`:

```php
protected $monitorId;
```

I can't quite see why this would have cause the error I was seeing, but changing it to a `public` property resolved the issue.